# How to import an existing S3 bucket exported by a stack, into another stack via CloudFormation YAML

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, yaml, aws-cloudformation

Something like the below CloudformationYAML works. I end up with a lambda function that's getting triggered whenever a new object shows up on the S3 bucket.

```
Resources:
  myS3BucketResource:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Ref myS3BucketName
      AccessControl: Private
      VersioningConfiguration:
        Status: Enabled

LambdaFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: main.handler
      CodeUri:
        Bucket: !Ref CodeBucketName
        Key: !Ref CodeKey
      Role: !GetAtt
        - LambdaRole
        - Arn
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      Timeout: !Ref LambdaTimeOut
      MemorySize: !Ref LambdaMemory
      FunctionName: !Sub '${Environment}-${FunctionName}'
      Events:
        S3Event:
          Type: S3
          Properties:
            Bucket: !Ref myS3BucketResource
            Events: 
              - 's3:ObjectCreated:Put'
```

However, what I need to do is to have the lambda function use an already existing S3 bucket, which was created by another stack. Note that in the above, the S3 bucket is getting created by the same CF template that's also creating the lambda.

I can't seem to just refer to the S3 buckets name in the `Bucket` property of the S3Event like below:

```
      Events:
        S3Event:
          Type: S3
          Properties:
            Bucket: !Ref myS3BucketName
            Events: 
              - 's3:ObjectCreated:Put'
```

So I'm thinking it's because it needed to be a resource rather than a string, at least based on the CF template above which works.

I read about `Fn::ImportValue` for importing something that's been exported by another stack -- which is the case for the S3 bucket I need to use. But I couldn't figure out how to specify that on the CF template.

Tried below, for example, but it's not working. With out without the `Type: AWS::S3::Bucket` line.

```
Resources:
  myS3BucketResource:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      Bucket:
        Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${exportedS3Bucket}"
```

Any lead would be appreciated. If there's a way to specify the `Bucket` without going through an import route, then that really would be best.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using the ARN instead of the name to configure the bucket?

Comment: It should work just fine with the bucket name. Are you obtaining the bucket name from a Parameter? Have you tried hard-coding it in `Bucket: 'my-bucket'` as a test?

Comment: I haven't tried the arn, I'll give that a shot. And I also haven't tried hadcoding the bucket name. But I don't see any reason why a !Ref to the bucket name which is provided as a parameter in the CF script would be different than hardcoding it. I'm referencing the same parameter in other parts of the CF script which is working just fine. But I'll try to hardcode it as well.

Comment: So, using the ARN or harcoding the bucket name resulted in the same error: "Transform AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31 failed with: Invalid Serverless Application Specification document. Number of errors found: 1. Resource with id [LambdaFunction] is invalid. Event with id [S3Event] is invalid. S3 events must reference an S3 bucket in the same template.. Rollback requested by user."

Answer (score 1):

> However, what I need to do is to have the lambda function use an already existing S3 bucket, which was created by another stack.

Assuming have have control on the `S3 bucket` bucket stack, you can [export](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html) it to be visible in other stacks, so that they can be [imported](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html) to them. You **correctly pointed that out already**.

Since you haven't provided a code for the bucket stack which exports its outputs, I have to base my answer on an **example**. In the example, note the use of `exportedBucket` name.

**bucket stack**:

```
Resources:
  myS3BucketResource:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket

Outputs:
  Name: 
    Value: !Ref myS3BucketResource
    Export:
      Name: exportedBucket  # <---- export bucket
```

**lambda stack** which will use bucket form the bucket stack:

```
LambdaFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: main.handler
      CodeUri:
        Bucket: !Ref CodeBucketName
        Key: !Ref CodeKey
      Role: !GetAtt
        - LambdaRole
        - Arn
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      Timeout: !Ref LambdaTimeOut
      MemorySize: !Ref LambdaMemory
      FunctionName: !Sub '${Environment}-${FunctionName}'
      Events:
        S3Event:
          Type: S3
          Properties:
            Bucket: !ImportValue exportedBucket  # <---- import bucket
            Events: 
              - 's3:ObjectCreated:Put'
```

Comment: The bucket name is already being exported on the stack that created the S3 bucket.  Unfortunately, doing what you've mentioned above resulted in the same error as when I simply specified the bucket name on that `Bucket:` property of the `S3Event` (see error I've provided as a comment on the question) --- This actually makes sense as exporting the bucket name really just gives you the bucket name and not really the entire resource, right?  Which is the same as hardcoding it on there or referencing a parameter whose value is a string corresponding to the bucket name. So, still no joy!

Comment: Oh, I've missed something here. You are actually exporting the resource itself on the S3 stack, not the bucket name. I'll try that.

Comment: Unfortunately, even using the exported S3 resource ends up with the same error: "Transform AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31 failed with: Invalid Serverless Application Specification document. Number of errors found: 1. Resource with id [LambdaFunction] is invalid. Event with id [S3Event] is invalid. S3 events must reference an S3 bucket in the same template.. Rollback requested by user."

The error seems to indicate the S3 bucket needs to be on the same template.

Answer (score 0):

Found this AWS doc => https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-function-s3.html

There's this:

```
Bucket
S3 bucket name. This bucket must exist in the same template.

Type: String

Required: Yes

AWS CloudFormation Compatibility: This property is similar to the BucketName property of an AWS::S3::Bucket. This is a required field in SAM. This field only accepts a reference to the S3 bucket created in this template
```

And this YAML sample:

```
Events:
  S3Event:
    Type: S3
    Properties:
      Bucket:
        Ref: ImagesBucket     # This must be the name of an S3 bucket declared in the same template file
      Events: s3:ObjectCreated:*
      Filter:
        S3Key:
          Rules:
          - Name: prefix      # or "suffix"
            Value: value      # The value to search for in the S3 object key names
```

The comment on the YAML indicates that the S3 bucket needs to be "declared in the same template file". While the bit about `AWS CloudFormation Compatibility:` in the `Bucket` section indicates "This field only accepts a reference to the S3 bucket created in this template".

Unless this AWS doc just needs updating, It doesn't look like there's a way to add a Lambda event trigger using an existing S3 bucket via CF. And that doesn't bode well for my use case.